# PerformanceCounters on .NET 4.0 & Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-4.0, performancecounter

I have a program that works fine on `VS2008` and `Vista`, but I'm trying it on `Windows 7` and `VS2010` / `.NET Framework 4.0` and it's not working. Ultimately the problem is that [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.getcategories(VS.80).aspx) (and other `PerformanceCounterCategory` methods) is not working. I'm getting following:

> System.InvalidOperationException with the message "Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry."

I can reproduce this with the very simple program shown below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var pc in System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pc.CategoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

I did make sure I'm running the program as an **admin**. It doesn't matter if I run it with VS/Debugger attached or not. I don't have another machine with `Windows 7` or `VS2010` to test it on, so I'm not sure which is complicating things here (or both?). It is `Windows 7 x64` and I've tried forcing the app to run in both `x32` and `x64` but get the same results.

Comment: If you're not sure about it Windows vs .net version, you could try changing the project properties in VS to target .net 3.5, rebuild, and try again.  

Or you could build the same code on a vista/xp machine with 2008, and copy the exe to the Win7 machine.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It seems performance counters were corrupted on my system. Although I didn't follow [this post](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/59699-perfmon-counters-are-corrupted/) exactly, it led me to the solution. Here is what I did:

In an command prompt with administrator/elevate privileges typed the following:

```
lodctr /?
```

Useful stuff in there...

Then typed:

```
lodctr /R
```

According to the docs from the prior step, this gets windows to *rebuild the perf registry strings and info from scratch based on the current registry settings and backup INI files.* I have a feeling this is what did the magic. However, next I noticed the .NET performance counters were not there anymore so based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikedodd/archive/2004/10/17/243799.aspx) I typed the following to reload them:

```
lodctr "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.20506\corperfmonsymbols.ini"
```

Note that this path is for .NET Framework 4.0 on x64. You can imagine the path for other variations of the framework/platform. I'm *guessing* you should always load the counters from the highest version of the .NET framework that you have installed, but that is just a guess.

I hope this helps someone else someday!

Comment: Is there any idea as to what causes this to happen?

Comment: @JeremyK I'm not sure what causes it, but it seems to happen to a lot of people!

Comment: This was an annoying bug, thanks for the answer, fixed it for me too!

Comment: This answer just saved me a bunch of time too. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to start re-writing my code to find out what was wrong. Lucky I came across this, everything's working fine for me :)

Comment: I do love you, bro! Actually we need to rebuild from the ini file first, then lodctr /R, and it seems it needs to run with administrator access to succeed.

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having with Raven not working on starting the .exe. Thank you very much Scott.

Comment: I only had to run `lodctr /R` to resolve the same issue for me.

Comment: This did not seem to fix the issue for me. I updated the path to v4.0.30319, and it on x32 and x64 paths, it said "Counters for .NETFramework are already installed".

Comment: The .GetCategories command. The root cause of the issue was nVidia drivers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751789/performancecountercategory-getcategories-throws-exception-argumentexception

Comment: This is the path for Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012: lodctr /r %WINDIR%\Inf\.NETFramework\CORPerfMonSymbols.ini