# InvalidOperatioException while developing Microsoft Surface 2.0 application

Tags: c#, .net, pixelsense

I am developing a Microsoft Surface 2.0 application using Visual C# 2010 Express Edition. I have already installed the Surface 2.0 SDK and Runtime Environment on a Windows 7 (32 bit).

From the installed templates, I choose a new Surface WPF application and press F5. I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message -

> Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index 'Terminal
>   Services' was read from the registry.

The project is empty. I haven't added a single line of code yet. The same blank application works perfectly well on another desktop running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try here first: [PerformanceCounters on .NET 4.0 & Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540777/performancecounters-on-net-4-0-windows-7)

Most likely the performance counters are not loading in the registry, or at least not loaded properly. I know the question is different, but the symptoms are the same.

Comment: Sounds like for some reason the SDK installer wasn't able to register it's counters on this machine.  Try uninstall/reboot/reinstall/reboot for the SDK.

Comment: Cool. That is the most common reason for the exception you listed.

Answer (score 2):

Run `lodctr.exe /r` it will repair registry entries related to the perfmon counters.