# getting error Invalid value '' for parameter 'categoryName'. - logical disk

Tags: c#, linq, performancecounter

For some windows machine, I am getting error while trying to fetch performance category for `logical disk`, but for some window machine I am not getting this error.

Why this error appears for some window machines?

```
var processorCategory = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().FirstOrDefault(cat => cat.CategoryName == "LogicalDisk");
```

***message error :***

`System.ArgumentException: Invalid value '' for parameter 'categoryName'`.

Comment: what is datatype of CategoryName?

Comment: string data type

Comment: Can I see the declaration of CategoryName ? are you using any attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories() throws exception ArgumentException - Invalid value '' for parameter 'categoryName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751789/performancecountercategory-getcategories-throws-exception-argumentexception)