# How to find % time spent in GC for a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection

I've been trying to find out this value out for hours now and to no avail. It's beginning to become quite frustrating.

I see this "% time spent in GC" mentioned everywhere (like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx for example) but with no mention on how to retrieve it!

I've tried Visual Studio's memory profiler, ANTS (trial expired now), CLR Profiler, and PerfView. Where is this value stored so that I may read it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe)

1. Start perfmon and select the process you want to monitor.
2. Click on the big green "+" sign to add a performance counter.
3. In the "Add Counters" dialog, select ".NET CLR Memory"
4. Expand the counters under ".NET CLR Memory"
5. Scroll down and select "% Time in GC"

Comment: I don't see ".NET CLR Memory". Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/p2SYwKM.png

Comment: Also, how would it know it's from this one application and not system-wide?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Odd. My Windows 8.1 shows ".NET CLR Memory". I have an old screen shot from Windows XP that also shows ".NET CLR Memory." See https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=245. I don't know why it's not showing up in whatever version of Windows you're using.

Comment: @JohnSmith: When you select the counter you're interested, the lower listbox (Instances of selected object:) will show the applications. You can select All instances or the individual processes you're interested in.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540777/performancecounters-on-net-4-0-windows-7, which might be related.

Comment: I tried rebuilding the counters and it said it worked but it's still not there.